# How do I calculate the mean value of a part of an array using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, mean

So, I am doing a GIT based course as part of my learning curve. I need to calculate mean values of a specific month. Here is the full code:

Importing csv files and creating arrays for two different weather stations - Kumpula and Rovaniemi:

```
import numpy as np
fp = 'Kumpula_temps_May_Aug_2017.csv'
kumpula = np.genfromtxt(fp, delimiter=',')
fpr = 'Rovaniemi_temps_May_Aug_2017.csv'
rovaniemi = np.genfromtxt(fpr, delimiter=',')

station = kumpula[:, 0]
station_r = rovaniemi[:, 0]
date = kumpula [:, 1]
date2 = rovaniemi [:, 1]
temp = kumpula[:, 2]
temp2 = rovaniemi[:, 2]
temp_max = kumpula [:, 3]
temp_max_r = rovaniemi [:, 3]
temp_min = kumpula [:, 4]
temp_min_r = rovaniemi [:, 4]
celsius = kumpula [:, 5]
celsius_r = rovaniemi [:, 5]
```

Taking a subset of Kumpula for the month of May (such is the date format, that is good):

```
kumpula_may_mask = date >=201705010000
kumpula_may = kumpula[kumpula_may_mask]
```

How do I get the .mean value for the "temp" array of kumpula_may?

When I do:

```
print (temp.mean())
```

I get the mean value of kumpula, have tried variations with adding kumpula_may but I can't seem to manage. I presume this is a rather simple thing but I was unable to locate it on web (probably unable to do a proper search).

Comment: Isolate that part of the array, preferably with with slicing (a `view`) but it could also be a copy.  And take the mean of that.

Comment: yeah, if your mask is correct, `kumupla_may.mean()` should give you the mean of that slice.

Comment: kumpula_may.mean() gives me an Nan so I'll check my mask but I need the temp column from the kumpula_may_mean that is also a part of the kumpula. @hpaulj what do you mean by a view? I am not familiar with it. Are you referring to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_copies_and_views.htm                                               Should I create a copy of the temp name column from kumpula to serve as a new column in kumpula_may?

Comment: Check the contents of your arrays. With that use of `genfrontxt` dtype is float, and strings that were not valid numbers appear as `np.nan`. `nan` will mess up the mean.  `np.nanmean` can filter out the nan.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. Here.       print (np.nanmean(kumpula_may[:, 2]))                                      Took quite some time to manage to hit the syntax with how to add the column "temp" which is the third column with an index 2 but I managed.